# C# - locking if statements - moving variable

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a simple code with one moving variable and a few ranges. The variable either increases or decreases at pseudo-random and I have no control over it. The ranges are my if statements.

Each if statement has two commands and I need one of the two commands to be met and executed, before the code can move on.

The problem is the variable can move into a different range before one of the commands is executed, which forces the code to expect two different commands.

How can I keep the code from doing anything else until one of the commands is executed, despite where the variable goes?

Note: It is guaranteed that one of the commands will execute given enough time.

While loops have not worked as they are seen as infinite loops.
Bools such as "trigger one or two was executed == true/false" have also not worked, and trapping the code in a bool statement yields the same result as the while loop. I have also tried a switch statement, but it was no different that the collection of ifs below.

I have looked into using state machine and recursive methods, but at this time they are a little beyond me and don't know if they will work for me now.

The below code is a generic example:

```
    int MP = moving variable; //updated every iteration of the code
    int R3, R2, R1, S1, S2, S3; //static variables input by user- in descending order
    //MP usually starts between S1 and R1

    if(R3 < MP < R2)
    {
       command one; //an if statement that gives command when triggered
       command two; //another if statement
    }
    if(R2 < MP < R1)
    {
       command one;
       command two;
    }
    if(R1 < MP < S1)
    {
       command one;
       command two;
    }
    if(S1 < MP < S2)
    {
       command one;
       command two;
    }
    if(S2 < MP < S3)
    {
       command one;
       command two;
    }
```

If it helps, I can bring in the actual code, but I do believe I have narrowed down my problem to this and am portraying it as simple as I know how. I can also go into more detail about any part of this.

I am hoping this is as simple as me overlooking an option, or perhaps there is a something I have not learned about yet.

Thank you for your time

Edit- This is an automated trading algorithm. MP is a live feed from the broker for a specific commodity price and the ranges are price points that the user thinks the commodity price will reach. The two actions are placing buy or sell orders, which are executed when the price hits certain levels. Trouble arises because, one of the price points is inside a different range(the stop order for those who know about trading). So there is overlapping of if statements briefly. What is happening, is that the above or below range's orders are being executed before the stop order from a neighboring range. That is why I need one of the initial orders to execute, before new ones are submitted.

I am sure this only made things more confusing, that is why I am trying to keep it at a very conceptual level.
-end edit

Comment: "If it helps, I can bring in the actual code"  -- yes please. I have no idea what you mean by "moving variable". Judging from this: "The problem is the variable can move into a different range before one of the commands is executed", the best I can think of is you are running in a multi-threaded environment and one thread is changing that variable all the time while the other thread is more or less the code you have posted.

Comment: I absolutely do not understand one bit of your question. I have a feeling that this is an "X / Y" problem and you're approaching it the wrong way. Read through your question and try to explain it in detail to Rubber Ducky and see if it helps clarifying it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: Synchronization of elements of data in a multithreaded system is one of the harder things to get right, but I dont think that we are at that level of complexity yet. Your description sounds like you have a c# program (which is in your control) that accepts user input (that is not in control of). Is this close?

Comment: StingyJack, the only thing not in my control, is MP. MP is live data from a broker for the price of a commodity.
I wanted to keep this at a very conceptual level to prevent confusion, but that does not seem to work for everyone.

Comment: The terms used are probably what are creating most of the confusion as they are not common, but the concept was also a bit muddy. I think my description is close, but in this case another program is providing the input (or is yours reading the input from somewhere? That is an important detail).

Comment: By the terms being uncommon, i mean things like "moving variables" (they dont) and talking about c# as "script". While there is ability to use c# as a scripting language (.cscript/csx), its more commonly used to create compiled output (dll, exe).

Comment: @StingyJack That is a good question, and I am not sure I know the answer. I know the code is receiving the market info from an external source when the code calls for the info. I am not sure if that answers your question. The ranges are user inputs. 

And I see what you mean about my word choice now, I am still pretty new to coding. I will be sure to note those.

Answer (score 2):

Assign MP to a temporary variable and then do a while loop around your if statements. Re-assign MP to the temp variable on every iteration of the loop. That way you are guaranteed that the variable will not change in flight.

Comment: Thank you for the response TJF, I see what you are suggesting. Unfortunately, MP is required to meet the command conditions(I did not clarify this in the question, I apologize), so MP needs to keep moving. I added more info in my questions.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted, the value of MP *will not* change between when it is initialized and the bottom of the last `if` statement.

If you are concerned with whatever calling code you have running this method of yours in multiple threads, where by the time the second one is executed, the first one hasn't finished. Then you must put your values in a Queue(ConcurrentQueue more likely) and process them from there.

> That is why I need one of the initial orders to execute, before new
>   ones are submitted

Your statement here, screams "I need a processing Queue".

Comment: thank you, this is the kind of thing I was hoping to get. I don't know anything about Queues at the moment, but I will look into this for sure.